# Migrate App engine python application to Appscale platform

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, migration, appscale

How can I migrate a complete App Engine Python application to AppScale on Amazon EC2?

I need to migrate all datastore records, cron jobs, TaskQueues and indexes.

Answer (score 3):

Data can be downloaded via the bulk downloader/uploader from GAE. See this document on how to upload data to AppScale: https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/Uploading-and-downloading-data-%28bulkloader%29

AppScale Systems provides much faster migration tools as well.

Cron jobs and taskqueues are supported in AppScale.

Comment: Is it possible to run appscale on VPS ?

Comment: Yes, in fact it's recommended. See http://code.google.com/p/appscale for the wiki on running it for Xen and KVM.

Comment: Documentation is on the github wiki rather than google code: https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/